# How to make subtitle text smaller in Angular Material card

Tags: angular, angular-material

I learn Angular Material and wonder how to make the subtitle text smaller.
Look at the picture:

```
<mat-card-subtitle>press enter on search</mat-card-subtitle>
```

It has almost the same size as the title.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add the below code to your styles.css

```
.mat-card-subtitle{
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Excellent thanks can I also make text little dim like light gray?

Comment: aha, I notice I have <mat-card-subtitle> in other places and now they to are color read, can I create like a class `.mat-card-subtitle2{}` for this situation?

Comment: Thanks being a newbie I created a [new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56734689/how-can-i-make-it-so-only-this-mat-card-subtitle-in-this-above-header-gets-col) question about this