# How can I make it so only this `mat-card-subtitle` in this above header gets color red?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I learn Angular material and I have this code

```
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>Search for books</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>press enter on search</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
```

and this css

```
.mat-card-subtitle {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: red;
}
```

The problem is now all `<mat-card-subtitle>` gets the color red. How can I make it so only the `mat-card-subtitle` in this above header gets color red?

Comment: Have you tried using Browser Inspect Tool to find the real css class name for subtitle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a custom CSS class in
HTML

```
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>Search for books</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle class="red-text">press enter on search</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
```

CSS

```
.red-text {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: red !important;
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I would like the "press enter on search" to be centered under the title text, how to do that?

Comment: Try using text-align: center inside .red-text in CSS

Comment: @ExocetKid I have edited answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the mat-card-subtitle and give color to particular class

```
.classname{color:red}
```